# Refresh subreport without refreshing the main report

Tags: ssrs-2008, report, bids

I am using BIDS to develop a report that have many subreports in it. The subreports have buttons that change their data so the user can compare them by date. The main problem is that when i click the buttons all the report is refreshed and not only the subreport. That requery all the others subreports and takes a considerable amount of time. Is there any way i can refresh only the subreport without the need to requery everything all over again?

Thanks!